# I’m having trouble figuring out the logic in my custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Basically, as you can see in the code, I only want to run one of these API requests. If origCompId is passed, it runs `duplicateInstance`, otherwise, it runs `addNewInstance`. origCompId is a query parameter so it takes a second for it to update. This causes `addNewInstance` to run because origCompId begins as null. I feel like the logic is simple here, but for some reason, I’m just not seeing the solution.

I tried adding the `hasRendered` ref, as you can see, but that didn’t prevent it from happening. The problem is, that I need this hook to run when the app first loads. I can’t separate these API calls. If the user is loading the app for the first time, it’ll run `addNewInstance` and load their initial data. If the user duplicates their existing app, it’ll have origCompId and run `duplicateInstance`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { addNewInstance, duplicateInstance } from "../util/services";

const useAddInstanceToDB = (instance, compId, origCompId) => {
  const hasRendered = useRef<boolean | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    if (hasRendered.current) {
      if (instance && compId && origCompId) {
        duplicateInstance(instance, controller, compId, origCompId);
      } else if (instance && compId) {
        addNewInstance(instance, controller, compId);
      }
    }
    return () => {
      controller.abort();
      hasRendered.current = true;
    };
  }, [instance, compId, origCompId]);
};

export default useAddInstanceToDB;
```

Comment: I appreciate the formatting edit. I’ll be better about that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can set the initial props to null / undefined so that non of the statement will run before your api completes

```
useAddInstanceToDB(undefined, undefined, undefined);

const useAddInstanceToDB = (instance, compId, origCompId) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        if (origCompId) {
            if (instance && compId && origCompId !== -1) { // will not run when hook is inited
                duplicateInstance(instance, controller, compId, origCompId);
            } else if (instance && compId && origCompId === -1) { // also will not run when hook is inited, only run when instance and compId is defined
                addNewInstance(instance, controller, compId);
            }
        }
        return () => {
            controller.abort();
        };
    }, [instance, compId, origCompId]);
};
```

setOrigCompId to -1 if new instance is needed, or any value other than -1 if duplicate is needed

Possible to have better solutions and I am open for that

Comment: All of the arguments begin as null already, so I don’t think this would change anything. They’re all query parameters from the url. Thanks though!

Comment: Please check the edit to see if that helps. origCompId is inited to undefined/null so the nothing will run when mounted. When origCompId is updated, it will then check if it is -1 or not and run corresponding statement

Comment: I think this will work. I’ll give it a shot when I have my coffee and mark it as an answer if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run your side effect exactly when your component gets information about *origCompId* whether it exists or not. Right now your component just can't know when the data is loaded - so you can't do anything. So you need to tell it to your component - you can set *origCompId = -1* if it not exists (as suggested by previous author), but I advise you to create a new variable that will tell your component that all the data has loaded.